# permissions of script to change permissions?

Tags: shell-script, permissions

I have a VMWare VM that directly accesses some disks.  In order to run (without running vmware as su which has its own problems) I need to change the ownership of the devices.  I've done this manually using [Nemo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_%28software%29), so I know what needs to be performed.

Writing a shell script to do this, I wrote

```
chown john:john /dev/disk/by-id/blahblah  /dev/anotherblah  /dev/lastoneblah
```

I saved it as a file `drive-owner`, set the execute bit, then in a root shell changed its owner to root and set the +s special mode flag.

The result, according to ls, is `-rwsr-sr-x`.

**If I run that from a normal (non-root) shell, I get errors from chown, *Operation not permitted*.**
It runs without complaint from a root shell.

I seem to be missing the part that runs the script as root automatically.  I thought that was the purpose and function of the "setuid" permission, and [+s is how to specify it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod#Special_modes).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Setuid and setgid flags are ignored for shell scripts, for security reasons.

Comment: Undoubtedly correct in this case, but not universally true.

Comment: Well that would explain it. So how do I accomplish this?  This is a personal computer, so security isn't as much of an issue.

Comment: @hildred Yes, that has only been true for most systems released in the past ~20 years.

Comment: @JDługosz Use `sudo` instead.

Comment: @JDługosz, or super, the best way to wrap suid scripts.

Comment: I'd still rather not put the sudo password in a script file.

Comment: @JDługosz You can configure `sudo` not to ask for a password for `chown` when run by you.

Answer (score 1):

Following these steps:

- Try `sudo`
- Try `chmod +x script_path`
- If security does not matter, run `chmod 777 script_path`

Comment: You mean the directory that contains the script file?  I had left the file in a convenient place related to its purpose, but I suppose it should go in a place where scripts are kept, like a utilities directory.  What's the right place for it, esp. If I want to run it automatically when the machine is rebooted?

Comment: Hi Sorry for late reply, for the script to execute at the startup, you would have to put your script in /etc/init.d and create a symlink to /etc/rc.d . And of couse you would have to change the file pemission to executable.   
                                                                                
#chmod +x /etc/init.d/Script_name
#ln -s /etc/init.d/script_name /etc/rc.d/

Answer (score 0):

@hildred noted this in a comment above. I'll expand it into an Answer as I think it's the correct and highly recommended answer.

The [super](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/super/) command

> … allows specified users to execute scripts (or other commands) as if they were root; or it can set the uid, gid, and/or supplementary groups on a per-command basis before executing the command. **It is intended to be a secure alternative to making scripts setuid root**. Super also allows ordinary users to supply commands for execution by others; these execute with the uid, gid, and groups of the user offering the command.

(Emphasis mine).